# ValueError: "hostingstart.app" could not be imported

Tags: python, azure, flask, fastcgi, azure-web-app-service

Trying to create azure python web app for flask python, but getting the following error

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)   File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)   File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name) ValueError: "hostingstart.app" could not be imported
```

StdOut:

StdErr:

I tried to upgrade wfastcgi, after that i have changed to script location to new wfastcgi, it was throwing scripts handlers  scriptProcessor could not be found in  error

Folder structure:

```
WWWroot
 - hostingstart.py
 - view.py
 - web.config
```

hostingstart.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import view
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app
```

Web.Config

```
<configuration>   <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="hostingstart.app"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>   </appSettings>   <system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
     <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"           
    scriptProcessor="D:\Python34\python.exe|D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py"
          resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install `python extension version` following below steps,instead of using azure web app self-brought versions.

Step 1 : Add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.1 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you deploy successfully, you could see following structure in the `KUDU` path: `D:\home\site\wwwroot>`.

[image]

If you want to use additional python package, please go on.

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via `python -m pip install pyodbc`

[image]